# For every $f \in L(I)$ there is a sequence of stepfunctions $\phi _ n $such that : $lim \int_{a}^{b}|f-\phi_n | = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

For every $f \in L(I)$ there is a sequence of stepfunctions $\phi _ n $such that : $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^{b}|f-\phi_n | = 0$  ?

1. Showing that for every $f\in L(I) $ there is a sequence of stepfunctions $\phi_{n}$

We know that the stepfunction and a function from $f\in L^+(I)$ are related defined by: $\int_{a}^{b} f dx := \lim \int_{a}^{b} \phi_{n} dx $

But f is from $L(I)$, so it is not clear that it is also $f\in L+(I)$; by defining $g,h \in L^+ (I)$ we can set:

$\int_{a}^{b} f dx := \int_{a}^{b} g dx - \int _{a}^{b} h dx $ , as both h and g can be written as the limits of the integrals of their stepfunctions. I am not sure how to go on from here. Appreciate if somebody could show me how to go on from here!

Answer (score 2):

You know the building blocks. Let's put them together. We can find two sequences of nonnegative step functions $s_n$, $t_n$ so that $s_n \le g$, $t_n \le h$, $s_n \to g$ and $t_n \to h$ as $n \to \infty$. Put $\phi_n = s_n - t_n$. Now by the triangle inequality:
$$
|f - \phi_n| = |(g - h) - (s_n - t_n)| = |(g - s_n) - (h - t_n)| \le |g - s_n| + |h - t_n|
$$

Integrate both sides on $[a, b]$ and take the limit as $n \to \infty$. Since $g$ and $s_n$ are both nonnegative and $s_n \le g$, we have $|g - s_n| \le |g|$ and we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to get:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b |g - s_n| \,dx = \int_a^b \lim_{n \to \infty} |g - s_n| \,dx = 0
$$

The same applies to $|h - t_n|$ and the desired result follows.